# MongoDB Java list all database users

Tags: java, mongodb, database

I'm currently creating a Java application that connects with a MongoDB and performs various data base operations such as find, insert and update from the application.

I created a dialog form from were a user can add multiple users `(using method addUser(String username, char[] passwd, boolean readOnly) )` with both the read and readwrite roles. I would like to be able to list all users by clicking a button from this dialog box and then right clicking on a specific user to be able to delete the users. `(using method removeUser(String username))`.

The problem is that after several research on the net I cannot find any library that provides such method (to return all the users) or I have no idea on how to get this result.

This is an assignment however it is not a specific question since the assignment is more related to the database operations. However I would like to add this functionality since it will be quite cool. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Mongo user accounts are listed in the collection `system.users`in the `admin` database.

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/system-users-collection/ for the data format.

Alternatively you can use the command `usersInfo`:

```
BasicDBObject dbStats = new BasicDBObject("usersInfo", 1);
CommandResult command = db.command(dbStats);
System.out.println(command.get("users"));
BasicDBList users = (BasicDBList) command.get("users");
for (Object u : users) {
    String username = (String) ((BasicDBObject) u).get("user");
    System.out.println(username);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Robert this worked fine. Can you please explain how I am going to return only the user names instead of the entire document from the result set.

Answer (score 1):

I've also faced this problem. Because the first answer(Robert's answer) is old, I gave my new answer;

Firstly, this is my Maven info:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Secondly, I used the runCommand of JDK, you can check the API doc as well. This is the theory link: [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/usersInfo/), the most important info:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bKgD.png)

Finally, my code:

```
Document dbStats = new Document("usersInfo", 1);
Document command = db.runCommand(dbStats);
ArrayList<Document> users = (ArrayList<Document>) command.get("users");
System.out.println(users);
```